# Adding an image to tableview cell: storyboard or programmatically, or both?

Tags: uitableview, uiimage, xcode6

When adding an image to a tableview cell, I know I can add it via the Interface Builder by going to the Attributes Inspector and adding it via the Images drop down ( once I have selected a style of cell that supports an image)

As far as I know I can add the image programmatically to my code in my main tableviewcontroller.

But I'm just not sure if I have to do both to get the image to appear in a tableview cell?
Do I have to add it manually into my Storyboard first, and then in code?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I dont see any reason for creating cells using storyboard (maybe you mean just Interface builder?)

I prefer making this using Interface builder (in NIB file), where I add UIImageView and then in code I am just setting correct image into it.

Another possibility (not good for beginners) is to make whole cell in code.

Comment: I do mean in Interface Builder I guess- where you can select tableviewcell and then go to its Attributes Inspector and select your image from drop down list there (assuming you have it already in supporting files).

Comment: I am using storyboard and interface builder- I just wanted to know if I can only set the image in code or if i have to set it in both.

Comment: You do not have to use Interfcace builder for this. It is possible to do it in code only. Just create UIImageView and add it as subview.

Comment: And how do you connect this to the storyboard?

Comment: If you want to do this using code, you will at first need to create cell. No matter if you have made it using Interface builder, or by code, but you need it.

If you have cell, you can add any component inside it as subview.

But as I can see, you are beginner, so I think you should make GUI of whole cell by using Interface builder. Its much easier.

Maybe, this can be helpfull for you: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: This was helpful too: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/10/ios-sdk-for-designers. Well, thanks for helping.

Comment: Happy to help. As questions should have an answer, I will post my last comment as answer to show it has been resolved.

Comment: It still hasn't been completely resolved so I can't accept your answer definitively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using code, you will at first need to create cell. No matter if you have made it using Interface builder, or by code, but you need it. If you have cell, you can add any component inside it as subview. But as I can see, you are beginner, so I think you should make GUI of whole cell by using Interface builder. Its much easier. Maybe, this can be helpfull for you:

[Tutorial](http://appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview)